# Authentication not working on publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

On my local machine my forms authentication works fine, I can login using the details saved in the server. If I enter the password wrong I'm not logged in, same with the username.

When I publish the site I can login using any details so long as the ModelState is correct. I don't understand why this would behave differently on my local machine to my server.

I am working off the same database, so that can't be the problem. It's as if my login model is being completely ignored when I publish the project.

Any idea why this might be? Do I need to add something to my web.config for this to work on my server? The strange thing is, this has been working fine for the last few months.

Comment: What MembershipProvider are you using? Are you publishing your application to a subfolder on the server, where web.config settings higher up in the hierarchy might be messing up your settings? Maybe add the relevant section of your web.config.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you copy/paste your login view, the action and your config file here? tHis will help us to examine your code well

Comment: do you use authentication filters to apply authentication? please include examples. Do you use simple membership? classic .Net membership? More information is better

Comment: As previous commenter have already pointed out, more specific info is needed. Please add as much as you can without violating NDA:s so your bounty will not go to waste.

Comment: just calm down.. open web config and review markup.. check differences if any you have made in this following days. review it fren you will get your answer your self.. :)

Comment: agreed with other comments. please show login & authentication code as well as tell us about your forms authentication config & database models

Comment: Maybe something wrong with cookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said:

"It's as if my login is being completely ignored when I published the project."

Then this might be the thing exactly happening, refer the following link to enable forms authentication in IIS7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope it helps.

[image]